# ESTA application still pending

Tags: esta

I have a B1/B2 visa, which is still valid, however my passport has expired. I am travelling to Orlando in March, so I applied for an ESTA, which I know now I did not need at the moment. The ESTA application is still pending after more than 72 hours. Should I be worried?

Comment: Have you got or applied for a new passport, or are you planning to?

Answer (score 5):

If your B1/B2 visa is current (not expired) then you can still use that along with your new passport.

When I enter the US I take both passports - the expired one that contains the valid visa, and the current one. The border agents look at both.

**To be extra clear** - you must take *both* passports.  The current valid passport, and your expired passport containing the current valid B1/B2 visa.